# Short story about a robot who finds the last human in the solar system?

Tags: story-identification, robots

The main thrust of the story is that a robot finds what may be the last human in the solar system.

He then attempts to "repair" the person (robot fashion) when the human complains about the low temperature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Story where a robot in the future last human, accidentally kills him when he 'switches the human off'](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140963/short-story-where-a-robot-in-the-future-last-human-accidentally-kills-him-when)

Comment: @PeterM It probably is a duplicate, but our policy is not to dupe-close story-ID questions until the answers to both have been confirmed to be correct. So I'm voting to leave this open since it hasn't been confirmed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually I made a slight mistake and the other story is really a dupe of this one based on submission dates.

Answer (score 9):

By coincidence, I remember this story. It is undeniably [Men are Different](http://hermiene.net/short-stories/men_are_different.html) by Allan Bloch. It's so short I can't actually describe it any better than the OP did.

> "One day, for no reason at all, he complained of the heat. I checked
>   his temperature and decided that his thermostat circuits were shot. I
>   had a kit of field spares with me, and he was obviously out of order,
>   so I went to work. I turned him off without any trouble. I pushed the
>   needle into his neck to operate the cut-off switch, and he stopped
>   moving, just like a Robot."

Comment: @Richard - nice edit. Adding that never occurred to me! And everyone else - it's worth a read. It'll take you 90 seconds, tops.

Comment: Updated link: http://www.gdhsenglish.com/thompson/assets/pdfs/ENG3U1%20pdf's/Short%20Stories/Men%20Are%20Different.pdf