# Short Story where a robot in the future last human, accidentally kills him when he 'switches the human off'

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Per the question title, I'm trying to locate a short story about a robot in the future.

He accidentally kills the last human when he 'switches him off'

Comment: We will need more information. Can you remember when you read it or where it was published? Or any other details of the story?

Comment: It might help to run through the checklists here - [How to ask a good Story-ID question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: http://www.urbanfantasist.com/latest-sci-fi--fantasy-poetry--flash-fiction/flash-fiction-humans-eh-by-soren-james

Answer (score 11):

Found it:

[Men are Different](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGkOHQypjPAhXGCMAKHXYFDBYQFgg3MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gdhsenglish.com%2Fthompson%2Fassets%2Fpdfs%2FENG3U1%2520pdf%27s%2FShort%2520Stories%2FMen%2520Are%2520Different.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEY1QgPMEu3106JGbHgC_SV9k9OPg&sig2=MiyvXlZPuSgKE8F8JZsPvQ) by Alan Bloch

> *One day, for no reason at all, he complained of the heat. I checked
>   his temperature and decided that his thermostat circuits were shot. I
>   had a kit of field spares with me, and he was obviously out of order,
>   so I went to work. I turned him off without any trouble. I pushed the
>   needle into his neck to operate the cut-off switch, and he stopped
>   moving, just like a Robot. But when I opened him up he wasn't the same
>   inside. And when I put him back together I couldn't get him running
>   again. Then he sort of weathered away—and by the time I was ready to
>   come home, about a year later, there was nothing left of him but
>   bones. Yes, Men are indeed different.*

Comment: And a dupe of; [Short story about a robot who finds the last human in the solar system?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53300/20774)

Comment: @Valorum - Not without an acceptance on the other one.

Comment: @Adamant - Nope, and hence why I haven't dupe-hammered it with my gold badge.

Comment: @Valorum - I suppose, but why suggest that it might be a duplicate (thus possibly causing people to VTC)?

Comment: @Adamant - If they do, I shall briefly explain the rules and use my gold badge to un-dupe it. No harm, no foul.